# Как переместить элементы из одной таблицы в другую при определённом условии?

Tags: lua, таблицы, перемещение

```lua
TableA = {}
TableB = {}

TableA[1] = "start"
TableA[2] = "context"
TableA[3] = "rock"

If(condition)then
  -- Перемещение элементов из TableA в TableB. Как это сделать?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, что у вас вызвало затруднения.  Вот
код для примера:

```lua
a = {
  [1] = "start",
  [2] = "context",
  [3] = "rock",
}

b = {
  [99] = "theend",
}

appletreesonmars = true

if appletreesonmars then
  for k, _ in pairs(a) do
    b[k] = a[k]
  end
end
```

Comment: стоит также заметить, что это все-таки не перемещение (и даже не копирование). Сдесь во вторую таблицу будут добавлены ссылки на элементы из первой таблицы. Так что в случае изменения объекта в первой таблице это изменение произойдет и во второй (это стоит учесть при "перемещении" таблиц, так как строки или числа невозможно изменить, можно только присвоить новое значение)

Answer (score 0):

```lua
-- Перемещает все поля из исходных таблиц в таблицу t и возвращает t.
-- Если ключ существует в нескольких таблицах,
-- используется значение самой правой таблицы.
function merge(t, ...)
  for i = 1, select("#", ...) do
    local x = select(i, ...)
    if x then
      for k, v in pairs(x) do
        t[k] = v -- Копирует поля
        x[k] = nil -- Удаляет поля из исходных таблиц (вам это нужно?)
      end
    end
  end
  return t
end

-- Эта библиотека просто для удобства отладки.
-- Всё что она делает - приводит таблицу к читаемой строке.
-- https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua
inspect = require "inspect"

function debug(msg)
  print("\n" .. msg .. ":")
  print("A: " .. inspect(A))
  print("B: " .. inspect(B))
end

A = {[1] = "start", [2] = "context", [3] = "rock"}
B = {[99] = "end"}

debug("Было")

merge(B, A)
debug("Стало")

A[1] = "new"
debug("Изменения в А не влияют на B")
```

Результат:

```
Было:
A: { "start", "context", "rock" }
B: {
  [99] = "end"
}

Стало:
A: {}
B: { "start", "context", "rock",
  [99] = "end"
}

Изменения в А не влияют на B:
A: { "new" }
B: { "start", "context", "rock",
  [99] = "end"
}
```